# Variation on a Waltz by Diabelli - Liszt

Tags: piano

I was looking for a recording of this piece and the top two youtube results are 2 different pieces both with S. 147, what is the actual one? [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWaKvN8lcJE) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DFP4Q5rGL8)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems more a piece identification question, which is even off-topic on Music Fans.

Comment: Consult the [sheet music](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/a/ae/IMSLP04667-Liszt_-_S147_Variation_on_a_Waltz_by_Diabelli.pdf), or just listen past the 1:00 mark in the second one. The second video starts with the original Diabelli material; the first leaves it out and starts with Liszt's variation.